# How to learn a niche language, i.e. Kazakh?

Tags: resource-request, turkic-languages

I am learning Kazakh.

There are maybe a total of 10 teachers of this language with a curriculum and none of them know grammar past declension.

Google translate is no help either.

I've had to use research papers to learn grammar and Turkish online resources to compare.

I have a native Kazakh speaker with me to tell me if a sentence is wrong or not, but they can't tell me why or how.

I am at a point where I understand grammar but I don't have resources to make advanced sentences on the go.

What should I do to improve?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. This is the right site to ask this question :-) I have removed the parentheses from the title because this question is specifically about Kazakh. Especially because we already have fairly similar general questions: [How can I get over lack of learning resources in "minor languages"](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/4110/800) and [How to learn a language for which very few resources are available?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/4211/800).

Comment: Isaac, if you have a Kazakh speaker, ask then to find a schoolteacher for you in Kazakhstan. I am sure a bunch of them would be delighted to help you.  Also, here is Nazarbayev University which surely has tons of people who would help you and the site has a pop-up help widget: https://nu.edu.kz/academics/allschools It's hard to believe that people don't think of universities/schools as a place to find teachers. Those two previous answers do not suggest those. [sigh]

Comment: Unfortunately good Kazakh teachers are few and far between. Kazakh academia has a very bad reputation for not so much teaching and more so demanding bribes and pay-offs. Let's just say those Kazakh speakers you mentioned don't have too much good to say about them.

Comment: @IsaacSechslingloff You can't be serious. I am telling you that a university is **probably** the best place to find someone. Who cares what the reputation of Kazakh academia is?? Are you looking for someone who can explain the grammar or not? If you discount every person at that university, good luck.  There are other (secondary and universities) schools in Kazakhstan. Use what you know and look for schools with the right domain name: site:.kz

Comment: https://astanatimes.com/2017/02/new-app-makes-learning-kazakh-language-easier/

Answer (score 1):

Try Ph.D John Doyle Wagner's (Duke University) grammar paper for Kazakh.
[kazakh-grammar.pdf](https://slaviccenters.duke.edu/sites/slaviccenters.duke.edu/files/file-attachments/kazakh-grammar.pdf)

Originally grammar similar to old Turkish, but given the fact they were under influence of USSR for a longtime it's separated a bit.

You can here some words [here](http://learn101.org/kazakh_grammar.php). Grammar structure is really similar to Turkish. There are no prefixes, nor genders. Just suffixes.
You use plural when you are formal. Once you are memorized the words, rest will be like lego blocks.

Finally this link seems helpful. You can find some videos here as well.
https://dimash.fandom.com/wiki/Learn_Kazakh_here