# How to learn Malayalam without any resources

Tags: learning-methods, resource-request, self-learning

I've been interested in learning a language called Malayalam. The problem is though, there is a complete absence of any well-written comprehensive Malayalam textbooks or grammar guides for English-speaking learners of Malayalam. There are some terrible ones written by random people on Amazon, however no real learning resources (except a university course written by the PeaceCorps, which is ok, but only has a limited amount of content). I would start by using basic materials, but the problem is I don't know enough vocab or grammar to work my way through anything, and I can't find a good, reliable, professionally-made  English-Malayalam dictionary for reference.

Has anyone else had any experience learning Malayalam, or any language with an absence of learning materials? If so, how did you go about learning it e.g. techniques, learning materials?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I learn a language with little documentation/resources (Georgian)?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2849/how-can-i-learn-a-language-with-little-documentation-resources-georgian)

Comment: See also: [How can I get over lack of learning resources in “minor languages”](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/4110/)

Comment: Language exchange.

Comment: What about children's books? They usually have limited vocabulary and use simple constructions. You would have to do a lot of figuring out of the grammar, but I for one find that quite interesting.

Comment: Hi sambeaz6! Welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange! You are faced with an interesting problem, but could you please [edit] your question to clarify what you want to focus on? I.e. either (a) a resource request for Malayalam or (b) a general question that does not focus on Malayalam (i.e. how do you learn *any* language with few resources?)? We already have two questions that are similarly unfocused (one involving [Georgian](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2849/800) and one involving [Cantonese](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/4110/800)).

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe  Yeah sure. I've changed the title.

Answer (score 1):

I'm learning Malayalam, I know that it is super hard to find the learning resources. I would like to recommended some resource:

- I found one app named Ling app from their YouTube or some resource that they promote they have Malayalam. I have tried this app since Feb until now, it is pretty good and enjoyed using the app, like you can learn vocabularies, grammar, speaking from speaking game or listening. So I think this is one of the effective resources. You can learn from your native language so this is way that more understand, I love this feature.
- Another learning resource is YouTube. This is the basic one; although still have a few channels teaching Malayalam, it is better than nothing. I hope this can help!